# How to link Virtuoso distributed version to Hadoop

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, sparql, rdf, virtuoso

I Have a cluster of 4 nodes, I installed Hadoop+ Spark (GraphX)...

Now I have to process a big RDF dataset, 
my question is : Can I install Virtuoso on the cluster so to store this RDF datasets and to be able to execute SPARQL distributed queries?

To the best of your knowledge, I need a web endpoint to allow users putting their SPARQL Queries.

in other words: is Virtuoso a good solution that works in a hadoop cluster, and can use SPARK to execute the distributed queries?

Comment: I don't know if Virtuoso has some Hadoop adapter but they have an own cluster edition (which is mostly commercial I think).The question is also what means "big RDF dataset"? Virtuoso open source single server edition works also for big datasets like also other triple stores like GraphDB or Stardog will do.

Comment: Besides that, there are plenty approaches for SPARQL on Hadoop or Apache Spark, just use a search engine of your choice to find them.

Comment: all right, there are a lot of technologies for RDF dataset on Hadoop. but I want to use the strength of virtuoso

Comment: all right, there are a lot of technologies for RDF dataset on Hadoop. but I want to use the strength of virtuoso. could you propose me an open source RDF store with a SPARQL endpoint?

Comment: More detail about what you're trying to do would help in providing relevant advice. Since you say you definitely want to use Virtuoso, you might consider asking on the [OpenLink Community Forum](http://community.openlinksw.com/) -- including providing the additional details!

Comment: Also asked (without much additional detail) on [OpenLink Community Forum](https://community.openlinksw.com/t/how-to-link-virtuoso-distributed-version-to-hadoop/1424).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Apache Spark website](https://spark.apache.org/) indicates that [**Spark SQL**](https://spark.apache.org/sql/) can be used to query across JDBC and JSON data sources --

> DataFrames and SQL provide a common way to access a variety of data sources, including Hive, Avro, Parquet, ORC, **JSON, and JDBC**. You can even join data across these sources.

Virtuoso (both Open Source and Enterprise Edition) can deliver SPARQL results as JSON serializations, so that is an option.

We ([OpenLink Software](https://openlinksw.com/)) also provide JDBC drivers for Virtuoso (again, both Open Source and Enterprise Edition), so that is also an option.

We are not Apache Spark experts, so we cannot provide much guidance for getting these working beyond assisting with Virtuoso JDBC URLs and/or retrieving SPARQL query results in JSON serialization.

---

In the other direction, Virtuoso (Enterprise Edition; not Open Source Edition) can be used to query against external ODBC data sources, and there are ODBC drivers available for Hadoop/SPARK data sources, so this is also an option.

We are not Apache Spark experts, so we cannot provide much guidance for getting their drivers working, but once you have a functional ODBC DSN on the Virtuoso host, we can assist in getting Virtuoso connected to and querying against it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you seeking to upload RDF datasets from your Hadoop Cluster using SPARK jobs? If so, you can use JDBC and the connection to Virtuoso.

I stumbled upon a [Dzone doc that covers SPARK and JDBC](https://dzone.com/articles/the-right-way-to-use-spark-and-jdbc) which once understood you can apply to Virtuoso via its ability to process [SPARQL queries via SQL connections](https://community.openlinksw.com/t/virtuoso-odbc-jdbc-and-ado-net-drivers-for-the-lod-cloud-knowledge-graph/1550).

I hope that helps, if not, we can discuss further.